# Python - How to recall the correct function

Tags: python

I'm getting an error I cannot fix, it will be shown below. Moreover, is the code optimized enough seen as a professional coder?

I'm trying to write a class which I will be able to recall throughout my project.

1. Do you have any reference on how to code the first `__init__()` block without mentioning the data source, but referencing to it later?
2. How do I recall the simple function `get_sd()`? It seems it's missing the end argument, but it's there.

Here is my code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import datetime as dt
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
 import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
 import numpy as np
 import math

 yf.pdr_override()

 class Ret:
    def __init__(self, ticker, start, end):
       data = yf.download(ticker, start, end, actions=True)
       self.returns = data["Return"] = (data["Close"] - data["Close"].shift(1)) / data["Close"].shift(1)
       self.CumRet = data["CumRet"] = data["Return"].cumsum()
       self.RetDiv = data["RetDiv"] = (returns + data["Dividends"] / data["Close"])
       self.CumRetDiv = data["CumRetDiv"] = data["RetDiv"].cumsum()

    def get_sd(self, ticker, start, end):
       return self.returns

    stocks = ["MMM",]
    start = "2006-01-01"
    # input("Enter start year") +
    end = dt.date.today()

    Ret.get_sd("AAPL", start, end)
    print(aapl)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ruleb/Desktop/python test/Ptf_Project/Get_data_prices.py", line 51, in <module>
  Ret.get_sd("AAPL", start, end)
  TypeError: get_sd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end'

  Process finished with exit code 1
```

**EDIT** I tried to amend like this.:

```
stocks = ["MMM"]
start = "2008-01-01"
end = dt.date.today()


class Ret:
    def __init__(self, ticker, start, end):
    return

    def get_sd(self):
    return np.std(self.Returns)

    def get_data(self):
    data = yf.download(ticker, start, end, actions=True)
    self.Returns = data["Return"] = (data["Close"] - data["Close"].shift(1)) / data["Close"].shift(1)
    self.CumRet = data["CumRet"] = data["Return"].cumsum()
    self.RetDiv = data["RetDiv"] = (data["Return"] + data["Dividends"] / data["Close"])
    self.CumRetDiv = data["CumRetDiv"] = data["RetDiv"].cumsum()
    return data

 myRet = Ret(stocks,start,end)
 myData = myRet.get_data
 print(myData)
```

But I get this:

```
<bound method Ret.get_data of <__main__.Ret object at 0x031ED310>>
```

Comment: Is this the actual indentation of your code? If so you need to de-indent the lines from `stocks = ["MMM"}` till the end, as they do not belong to the class definition.

Comment: Also: you should first instantiate the `Ret` class with something like `myRet = Ret()`, then you can call the method `get_sd` on `myRet`: `myRet.get_sd()`.

Comment: i amended as per above, made it worse i think. Maybe i did not understand something of the recalls

Comment: You need to call the method, you should add parenthesis: `myRet.get_data()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code in the edited version of the question, you need to call the method: change `myRet.get_data` to `myRet.get_data()`.

```
class Ret:
    def __init__(self):
        # it is a good practice to initialize the attributes
        # in '__init__()', even if you are going to use them later
        self.Returns = None
        self.CumRet = None
        self.RetDiv = None
        self.CumRetDiv = None

    def get_sd(self):
        return np.std(self.Returns)

    def get_data(self):
        data = yf.download(ticker, start, end, actions=True)

        self.Returns = data["Return"] = (data["Close"] - data["Close"].shift(1)) / data["Close"].shift(1)
        self.CumRet = data["CumRet"] = data["Return"].cumsum()
        self.RetDiv = data["RetDiv"] = (data["Return"] + data["Dividends"] / data["Close"])
        self.CumRetDiv = data["CumRetDiv"] = data["RetDiv"].cumsum()

        return data

myRet = Ret(stocks, start, end)
myData = myRet.get_data()
print(myData)
```